# MySQL ISNULL SQL code equivalency for PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, isnull

I am new to PostgreSQL and I am constantly learning. I am following a mini-project guideline that uses MySQL but I prefer working in PostgreSQL. I have read many StackOverflow answers that have helped me in the past, but I am completely stuck on this one. My code is:

```
Select a.parcelid, a.propertyaddress, b.parcelid, b.propertyaddress,
    ISNULL(a.propertyaddress, b.propertyaddress)
    From public.nashhousing a
    JOIN public.nashhousing b 
        on a.parcelid = b.parcelid
        AND a.uniqueid <> b.uniqueid
    Where a.propertyaddress is null
```

The error message I keep receiving is:

```
ERROR:  function isnull(text, text) does not exist
LINE 2: ISNULL(a.propertyaddress, b.propertyaddress)
        ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

Can anyone please assist me?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`COALESCE` is the sql standard version of this function that probably works in most database. i.e., `coalesce(a.propertyaddress, b.propertyaddress)`

COALESCE returns the first non-null value, so it can work with two (as in your case) or more values. We could also, for instance, write `coalesce(a.propertyaddress, b.propertyaddress, 'no address!')` and it would return the third value if both of the first two are null.

Here's the official postgres documentation:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-COALESCE-NVL-IFNULL

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked wonders and my headache is finally gone!

Answer (score 1):

I think your example is wrong in that you are looking for a alternate to [IFNULL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/flow-control-functions.html#function_ifnull) not [ISNULL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_isnull) as `ISNULL` takes only a single argument. The alternate and SQL standard function is [COALESCE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-COALESCE-NVL-IFNULL).